# Get partial language URL parameters and Insert to DE in SFMC

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, jquery, ssjs

We have an iframe form setup on a landing page with both English and French language preferences. I want to get the URL parameter that shows Language type and write that value to a Data Extension upon form submission.

Can the above be done using SSJS? Is jQuery a better option than Ampscript to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Just answering my own question :)

I solved it by passing an Ampscript variable, setting it up as a hidden field on form submit, and calling it during Post passing the subscriber's language to the data extension.

Something like this:

**Sign-up page:**

*(Ampscript)*

```
%%[
set @formlang = "en-CA" 
set @formlang = "fr-CA"
]%%
```

*(HTML)*

```
<input type="hidden" name="formlang" id="formlang" value="%%=v(@formlang)=%%"/>
```

**Confirmation page** - on POST

*(Ampscript)*

```
%%[
set @formlang = RequestParameter("formlang");   
UpsertData ('lang', @formlang)
]%%
```

if you have an alternative to the above, share it here - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In your example, the language it's going to be always "fr-CA" as you are overwritting the @formlang variable (remember the code iscompiled top-down).

If you want the user to choose the language, insert a select option instead of the hidden. If you want to autoselect the preferenced language for the user, first retrieve the language value from the data extension: 
a) and update the option with the selected attribute. (to allow the user to modifiy the value)
b) print the value in your hidden field %%v=()=%%